# Rotation Animation In React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to make rotation animation like clock. Needle will rotate inside the clock.

[image: Clock Image]

1. How to set axis for needle.
2. How to achieve Android's Frame Layout functionality in React-Native.

Comment: Create SVG circle. Fill it with any color. Then get the bounding box. Draw a `path` from center to top middle position of bounding box. Keep modifying the rotation value of path line based on requirement. That's it.